# improve performance of sed (in cygwin called from cmd.exe)

Tags: bash, optimization, sed, cmd, cygwin

A binary C++ application uses `CreateProcess` to launch a shell command (cygwin's `bash.exe`), running a `sed` command in turn.

That shell command gets a file, puts every line with null characters in it to one file, and puts every line without a null character to a different file.

The search/output part is working, the issue is that it takes about 12 seconds to run for a 66 meg file.  I may have to run files up to 200 megs through this process, so I'd like some help on how to optimize this as much as possible.  It has to all be in a single line, and can't be in a bash script.  The command I'm using is below:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c "cat c:'\'sedtest'\'BIGFILE.txt | sed -r -ne '/\x0+/ p' > c:'\'sedtest'\'nullfile.txt; cat c:'\'sedtest'\'BIGFILE.txt | sed -r -e '/\x0+/d' > c:'\'sedtest'\'notnullfile.txt"
```

That is not what the string looks like within the C++ application, by the way, that's just what gets passed to the shell after escaping.  It works perfectly, it just takes kind of a long time.  I do not think the C++ code is relevant at the moment, but I will post it if someone thinks it is required.

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. Also, your goal itself is very odd. "Every line with a null character" — well, lines usually only make sense (or are only useful) in text files (I'm not saying binary files do not have lines, just that `\n` isn't really special and could be anywhere), and text files by definition should not contain null characters. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is for some reason we have plaintext files with null characters.  I know they _shouldn't_ contain null characters, but they _do_ and I need to remove the lines that have them so they can be sent back for correction, while we can move on to process only the lines of the file that are correct.

Comment: So I guess this is a one-time job? Then just wait for a while...

Comment: No, this isn't a one-time job.  I get these files all the time.  These files are huge and our current system has to parse the whole thing only to find a null somewhere in the middle and crap out and not process anything.  This takes a long time and the nulls need to be removed before processing so things that can't be processed won't waste any time clogging up our system, and we process only the things that need to be processed.  I really just interested in knowing if there is a way to speed up the sed command and not how everything would be better if I threw it all out and did something else.

Comment: Okay, what about `grep -Pa '\x00'` and `grep -vPa '\x00'`? Can you see if they're a little bit faster? You can also write a custom python/perl/etc. script that combines your two tasks so that you don't need to read and process twice. I'm afraid bash and awk (variants that I know of) won't help here because their strings won't hold NULL.

Comment: By the way, since you're already in C++, why don't you just process the files in C++? Why do you need to shell out?

Comment: Well, as for the last question, to be honest, I do not think I can write a faster parser than sed, or whatever other tool is faster if sed is not the fastest.  I know sed is insanely optimized for performance, and even if I could write something just as fast, I don't think it would be faster than sed is.  It's also a lot more work.  I can't try the grep suggestion right now as I have to leave in a few minutes, but I'll keep this page open and check it tomorrow.  Thanks for the suggestions.  I do not know if I am allowed to use python/perl, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Apparently I forgot `sed` can also open multiple files with the `w` command. However, I ran some benchmarks and `sed -n -e '/\x00/ w nulls' -e '/\x00/ !w nonnulls' input` is actually slower than `sed -n '/\x00/ p' input >nulls && sed '/\x00/ d' input >nonnulls`. `grep` is also significantly slower in my benchmarks.

Comment: Another bit of follow up: `grep` performance isn't significantly slower actually; it's at most twice slower and usually just a little bit slower than the combined `sed`. I also wrote a perl equivalent and its performance is also roughly on par with everything else.